# get only one row from first table in table left join in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, subquery

I have two table 
1. Bog_post
2. blog_image

Now I want only one image from blog_image table.
I also save post id in blog_image table.
how can i do this query in laravel ?

Comment: is there relationships with two tables ? one to one or one to many ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model as "BlogImage" and edit it.

```
class BlogImage extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blog_image';

}
```

Then create a query with this model.

```
$blog_image = BlogImage::where('post_id',$post_id)->pluck('image')->first();
```

You can get just "image" column data in this way, as you want.

Also you can set releationship with this two tables. Here is [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: thanks. but I need this, 
suppose I added one blog.
get last inserted id and save the image with this id in another table.
Now in image table I am uploaded more 2 or more image for same id.
But when i fethc recored it return all the image with BlogID -3. But i need only first image from ID-3

Comment: I see.. Well you can use first method ? I edited my answer